# how to prove mean value property for harmonic functions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

For a harmonic function $u(x)$, on domain $\Omega$ where $x \in \Omega \subset  \Bbb R^n  $, how to show that
$$ u(x) = \frac{1}{\omega_n R^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B_R(x)} u(\sigma) d\sigma$$
where $\omega_n$ is the area of the unit sphere $\partial B_1(x)$.
I am looking for simple case $n=2$ centered at $0$. An argument in my note uses the definition 
$\displaystyle  g(r) \overset{(def)}{=} \frac{1}{2\pi r }\int_{\partial B_r(0)} u(\sigma) d\sigma$ and shows that $g'(r) = 0$. I don't see how does it prove above? I think it proves $g(r) = \text{constant}$.

Comment: You are right, but what is that constant?

Comment: @John is it supposed to be $u(0)$ ??

Comment: Note that $g(r)$ is the average of $g$ over the circle of radius $r$. If $g$ is continuous, $g(r)$ should goes to $g(0)$. Of course one needs to prove that, though the proof is not difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: consider $\displaystyle\lim_{r\to 0}g(r)$.

Comment: all right, is $g(r) = g(0)$ ??

Comment: $g$ is not defined at $0$, but its limit at $0$ exists.

Comment: could you be a bit explicit in you answer?? I am not getting it :((

Comment: Ok, since $g'=0$, you have that $g$ is a constant. Therefore, $\displaystyle g(r)=\lim_{s\to 0}g(s)$. All you have to do is prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{s\to 0}g(s)=u(0)$.

Comment: i see ...${{{}}}$